# Using virtualenvwrapper in Eshell

Tags: eshell, python

I noticed that I can't use virtualenvwrapper commands (like `workon`) in an eshell but they do work within a shell environment. Is there a virtualenvwrapper-like mode for Emacs?

Comment: `virtualenvwrapper` (in melpa) gives the command `venv-workon` to switch environment, but for all emacs session too. http://wikemacs.org/index.php/Python#See_also However pyvenv looks more complete.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`virtualenvwrapper` (in melpa) gives the command `venv-workon` to switch environment, but for all emacs session too. It works with eshell with `venv-initialize-eshell`:

> support for eshell is turned on by calling venv-initialize-eshell.
>   After doing this, any new eshells you launch will be in the correct
>   virtualenv and have access to installed executables, etc. The mode
>   also provides a variety of virtualenvwrapper commands that work
>   identically to their bash/zsh counterparts (described in detail
>   below). Note that in contrast to how interactive shells work, Eshell
>   shares an environment with Emacs, so if you activate or deactivate in
>   one, the other is affected as well. Note that this requires the
>   variable eshell-modify-global-environment to be set to true. Running
>   venv-initialize-eshell causes this to occur. If this doesn't work for
>   you, open an issue! It's technically possible to separate the two, but
>   it requires some hacking around with the different namespaces that I
>   won't bother to do unless someone really needs it.

and on modifying the eshell prompt:

> Eshell prompt customization
>
> You also might want to have the name of your current virtualenv appear
>   on the eshell prompt. You can do this by a pretty similar mechanism,
>   just include venv-current-name in your eshell-prompt-function
>   somewhere. Here is a simple example of a prompt that includes the
>   current virtualenv name followed by a dollar sign:
>
> (setq eshell-prompt-function
>       (lambda ()
>         (concat venv-current-name " $ ")))
>
> Make sure you also adjust your eshell-prompt-regexp if you do this.
>
> More about customizing the eshell prompt on the EmacsWiki.

Works with (e)shells, has auto-activation, displays in the mode line.

- http://wikemacs.org/index.php/Python#See_also
- https://github.com/porterjamesj/virtualenvwrapper.el

I would be interested to know the differences betwwen it and pyvenv.

Answer (score 2):

[pyvenv](https://github.com/jorgenschaefer/pyvenv) lets you use a virtualenv from within Emacs.  Note however that due to some limitations of Emacs this package switches your **entire** Emacs session to a specific virtualenv.  If I remember correctly, it is not possible to switch just one buffer to a virtualenv.

Comment: I typically use my .dir-locals.el to switch the pyvenv per-project. pyvenv also has a tracking setting to switch automatically when switching buffers.